# Julia power operator ^ returns different value than python pow()

Tags: julia

i made a rsa-encryption demo to learn julia but ran into a problem.
this should be no issue of overflow and all values fit rsa criteria when i check with python code.
any pointers are welcome. julia is an awesome language and i would like to figure this out.

check these images to see my problem:
[image: Julia Code with Problem]
[image: Python Verification]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead, post the code as text so that we can copy paste it. Also, please boil down your example. We don't need to know about the `rsa` part. Just say something like *"Julia: `123^456=...`, Python `pow(123, 456)=...`"*. You can [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `BigInt(message)^used_e`, and similar. The problem you are seeing is integer overvflow before you convert to `BigInt`. Note that `powermod(BigInt(message), used_e, used_N)` will be much faster since it will keep all the intermediate numbers smaller.

Comment: thanks, your code works! I didn't know about this function... also pasting code is indeed usefull xD I will remember this for when i need help again

Answer (score 2):

Note that in Julia `x % y` is a synonym for the `rem(x, y)` function “from Euclidean division, returning a value of the same sign as `x`”, whereas for an RSA implementation, you need the `mod` function instead, where the result has the same sign as `y`. (But you really actually want `powermod` over `BigInt` here for performance.)

Comment: Since all the arguments for RSA are positive, `rem` and `mod` are the same.

Comment: @OscarSmith That is correct for the basic RSA formula, but users playing with asymmetric cryptography may soon move on to other algorithms (e.g., DSA) that involve substraction, and then the use of the correct mod operator becomes important, so I thought it was worth mentioning. I appreciate that the negative numbers in the original question are the result of an `Int` overflow, i.e. the user converting to `BigInt` too late.